# Label Tkinter Variable

Tags: python, variables, tkinter, label, frame

I created a quiz in tkinter , which goes from page to page and adding to the variable "score".
But if i want to display the final score it shows the initial value instead of the actual one.
Does somebody have a similar problem or an idea for a solution?

Thanks

```
import tkinter as tk                
from tkinter import font  as tkfont 



class SampleApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.title_font = tkfont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=18, weight="bold", slant="italic")

        # the container is where we'll stack a bunch of frames
        # on top of each other, then the one we want visible
        # will be raised above the others
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage,theme1page,theme2page,theme1Q1,theme1Q2,theme1Q3,\
                  theme1Q4,theme1Q5,theme2Q1,theme2Q2,theme2Q3,theme2Q4,theme2Q5, Results):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame

            # put all of the pages in the same location;
            # the one on the top of the stacking order
            # will be the one that is visible.
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("StartPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()
```

We directly show the last question page for simplicity. The variable score is the one we increase while answering correctly.

```
class theme1Q5(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="5.Question", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x")   



        Question15 = tk.Label(self, text="Which sentence is not true?")
        Question15.place(x=0, y = 30)

        controll15 = tk.IntVar()
        wrong151 = tk.Radiobutton(self, text="Neural Networks work bad with small amount of data", \
                                  variable= controll15,value=1)
        wrong152 = tk.Radiobutton(self, text="Concept of neural network exists since the middle of the mid-twentieth",\
                                 variable= controll15,value=0)  
        right15 = tk.Radiobutton(self, text="There is no learning rate parameter in training neural networks", \
                                 variable= controll15,value=5)
        wrong151.place(x=0, y=60)
        wrong152.place(x=0, y=80)
        right15.place(x=0, y=100)

        def scorer(event):
            if int(controll15.get()) > 2:
                global score
                score += 1 

        button = tk.Button(self, text="Result",command = lambda: controller.show_frame("Results") )
        button.bind("<Button-1>", scorer)
        button.pack(side="right")

#END THEME 1
```

This is the page for showing the actual result (score value). Problem is, while answering all questions correctly, it will show the score initial value (0). On the other hand, the scorecalc function assigned to "print score" button shows the right score... Seems like it can't show from first the actual value, but we have to click on a button to do so...

```
#RESULT PAGE
class Results(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Your Score:", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        button = tk.Button(self, text="return to Menu",
                               command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
        button.pack(side= "bottom")


        global score
        label = tk.Label(self, text= "%s / 5" %(score), font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack()
        def scorecalc():
            label = tk.Label(self, text="Your Score:", font=controller.title_font)
            label.pack(side="top", fill="x")
            label = tk.Label(self, text= "%s / 5" %(score), font=controller.title_font)
            label.pack()




        scorep= tk.Button(self, text ="print score", command=scorecalc)
        scorep.pack()





if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Are the 3 pages part of the same python file?

Comment: yes, they are all part of one file.

Comment: Where do you _define_ `score`?

Comment: This is way to much code. Please try to condense it down to a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

There are some major issues with your code. Using global variables while using classes is counter productive I think.

One of the major reason why your code does not work is due to the fact you are using variables where class attributes should be used. If you use a variable in a class then after `__init__` you will not be able to interact with that variable. be it a widget or a save value like a number or string.

We can fix this by adding the `self.` prefix to anything that is going to be interacted with from inside the class or from outside the class object.

Also your code does not actually show that you have a global variable called score so I added one to the global namespace for testing.

with that in mind you were using the variable name label for multiple labels. any time you are assigning a variable name they need to be unique.

I have combined the 3 sections of your code to provide a working example that will update the score. This example is not perfect but it is the minimum that is needed to be changed to get the results you are looking for.

Let me know if you have any question:

```
import tkinter as tk                
from tkinter import font  as tkfont 

score = 1

class theme1Q5(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="5.Question", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x")   

        Question15 = tk.Label(self, text="Which sentence is not true?")
        Question15.place(x=0, y = 30)

        self.controll15 = tk.IntVar()
        wrong151 = tk.Radiobutton(self, text="Neural Networks work bad with small amount of data",
                                  variable= self.controll15,value=1)
        wrong152 = tk.Radiobutton(self, text="Concept of neural network exists since the middle of the mid-twentieth",
                                 variable= self.controll15,value=0)  
        right15 = tk.Radiobutton(self, text="There is no learning rate parameter in training neural networks",
                                 variable= self.controll15,value=5)
        wrong151.place(x=0, y=60)
        wrong152.place(x=0, y=80)
        right15.place(x=0, y=100)

        button = tk.Button(self, text="Result",command = lambda: controller.show_frame("Results"))
        button.bind("<Button-1>", self.scorer)
        button.pack(side="right")

    def scorer(self, event = None):
        if int(self.controll15.get()) > 2:
            global score
            score += 1
            self.controller.frames["Results"].update_label()

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.title_font = tkfont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=18, weight="bold", slant="italic")
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (theme1Q5, Results):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("theme1Q5")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()

#RESULT PAGE
class Results(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Your Score:", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        button = tk.Button(self, text="return to Menu",
                               command=lambda: controller.show_frame("theme1Q5"))
        button.pack(side= "bottom")


        global score
        self.label2 = tk.Label(self, text= "%s / 5" %(score), font=self.controller.title_font)
        self.label2.pack()

    def update_label(self):
        global score
        self.label2.config(text= "%s / 5" %(score))
        print(score)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```